# gnome-terminal - how to get the pass/fail status of the invoked command

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

I'm running a command inside a gnome-terminal like this:

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x bash -c "<some_command>"
```

if i then check the pass/fail status of the last command using `$?` i always get 0, even if `<some_command>` fails.

Is there a way to reflect the pass/fail status of `<some_command>` to the original shell so `$?` will show the correct result?

Comment: Any reason to explicitly invoke a gnome-terminal?  Since you are already running one, why not execute "`<some_command>`" directly?

Comment: gnome-terminal don't reflect the status of executed command, neither do other terminal commands I know. Why are you using gnome-terminal for non-interactive work at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible because even with appending `exit $?` to the command, `bash` is a subprocess of `gnome-terminal`  which is a subprocess of your shell session.

Even if `gnome-terminal`'s subprocess (`bash`) exits abnormally, `gnome-terminal`'s GTK+ UI process still exits normally with 0.

This sounds like an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- rather than using `gnome-terminal` and checking the exit status, which is weird and convoluted, find the root of the problem you want to solve and chase that instead.

Comment: Hi cat. i don't think that this is an x/y problem because in this case x is very simple, <some_command> is a compilation command that i'm running on a remote session, and i run it in a gnome terminal because i want to keep the main session clean without many prints, but at the same time still see the progression of the compilation. what i want is that if the compilation fails, the main process would detect it and stop gracefully.

Comment: @user1845156 This sounds more "usability" than "programming" and I think you will get more answers of a higher quality on [unix.se].